# String To Time Returns False

Tags: php, laravel

I have a url param that looks like the following:

```
http://url?date=2017-01-01,2017-03-12
```

I am then exploding the string on the `,`

```
$date = explode(',', $request->query('date'));
```

When i dump out the string its fine.

```
array:2 [▼
  0 => "2017-01-01"
  1 => "2017-03-12"
]
```

I then generate the date

```
$dateOne = date('Y-m-d',strtotime($date[0]));
```

This returns: `1970-01-01`

but if do the second element of the array

```
$dateOne = date('Y-m-d',strtotime($date[1]));
```

I get a nice formatted date `2017-03-12`

I am so confused how this is happening.....

Any ideas?

Comment: And the `explode()` call would error

Comment: Yes was an example URL ill correct it

Comment: Try `var_dump($date[0])`, and make sure it looks like it should, and that the string length is 10.

Comment: `$date = explode(,$request->query('date'));` A little weird notation...
Should be: $date = explode(',', $request->query('date'));

Comment: Yes i have made the amends to it now!

Comment: Out of interest: Why are you trying to convert `2017-03-12` into `2017-03-12` The whole date conversion seems to serve no purpose!!!

Comment: Sorry :) wanted to help!

Comment: I have used Carbon and i have came across this error now `DateTime::__construct(): Failed to parse time string (2017-05-11) at position 0 (�): Unexpected character`

Comment: There must be something you are not telling us, as this works just fine using PHP5.3 through PHP7.1 when the input format is `YYYY-MM-DD`

Comment: There was a invalid character at the end of a query string from a copy and paste! Silly man!! Cheers for the help guys!

Answer (score 2):

The problem is the format of your data, strtotime function consider the date format by the separator character, in your case is the dash "-".
So, strtotime consider the date format d-m-y.
Replace the separator with a point "." and you solve the problem.

Ref: http://php.net/manual/it/function.strtotime.php#100144

Comment: You might also ask why OP is converting a date that is already in the format he wants at all

Comment: Using input format `YYYY-MM-DD` works fine on PHP5.3 through PHP7.1